# linear algebra - Parallel vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

The vector [c^2, c^3, c^4] is parallel to the vector [1,-2,4] with the same direction.

Not sure how to solve this since it asks to find C.

Comment: What do you think?  How do you show vectors are parallel?  What might you be able to do the make $(1,-2,4)$ have the right look?

Comment: The two vectors are parallel when there is an $a$ such that $[c^2,c^3,c^4]=a[1,-2,4]$. This gives you $3$ equations in the two unknowns $c$ and $a$: $c^2=a$, $c^3=-2a$, and $c^4=4a$. From the first and last you get that $a^2=4a$. Therefore either $a=0$ or $a=4$. If $a=0$ you get the solution $c=0$. It $a=4$, then $c=-2$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thus, $$c^2=k,$$ $$c^3=-2k$$ and $$c^4=4k,$$
which gives $$c^3=-2c^2$$ or
$$c^2(c+2)=0$$ and $c=-2$, $c=0$ they are valid.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative **by cross product**

$$\begin{vmatrix}e_1&e_2&e_3\\1&-2&4\\c^2&c^3&c^4\end{vmatrix}=(-2c^4-4c^3)e_1-(c^4-4c^2)e_2+(c^3+2c^2)e_3=\vec 0$$

that is for $c\neq0$

$$\begin{cases} 2c^4+4c^3=0\\c^4-4c^2=0\\c^3+2c^2=0\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases} c=-2\\c=\pm2\\c=-2\end{cases}\implies c=-2$$

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if wrong :

Assume $c \not =0$, real.

$(c^2,c^3,c^4) = c^2(1,c,c^2).$

Vector $(1,c,c^2)$ is parallel to $(c^2,c^3,c^4)$ (In the same direction).

Comparison of $(1,c,c^2)$ with $(1,-2,4)$ implies: $c=-2.$

Comment: that's correct Peter!

Comment: Thanks gimusi.Seems too easy.

Comment: Very good solution, simple and clear!

Comment: Thanks for your kind words.